# Can i prepare a Unity build on Xcode 8.2 for iOS 8.0 above only targeting arm64 and submit app to itunes without issues?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

**Situation-**
Xcode: 8.2
Required device capability is : metal
target iOS: 8.0

Above 3 shortens the supported devices to-
iphone 5s and above, all these devices have support for Arm64.

**Question**-
Can I make a build targeting only arm64 and submit to store without issues (/rejection)?

*Additional info*
there is a tag for required device capability as ARM64 but this seems to be supported only after iOS9.0 but i am targetting iOS8.0, dont know if i can achive what i want to do with it.

*In below image my app is supposed to run only in the orange section of devices*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5s5W.png

*List of Required Device Capabilities and min OS version req to use them*
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

*List of apple devices and supported device capabilities*
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

I cannot test this by actually uploading the build as I am creating this for a client so I will be sharing the ipa with him.

Comment: what about testing it with TestFlight?, for external testers there is a review made by Apple, that should give you some insights if what you have tried is actually possible.